# Apache Redirect https://www.subdomain.domain.com to https://subdomain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm getting kind of desperate after trying to redirect:

https://www.subdomain.domain.com -> https://subdomain.domain.com

for several hours now. I've taken another suggestion here and tried to work with it a couple of times but it doesn't work for my website.

I'd really appreacite the .htaccess rule for redirecting

https//www.subdomain.domain.com -> https//subdomain.domain.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @bogdan, it worked as expected and saved our time, really appreciate your help 